# Get phi, theta, doc.length, vocab, term.frequency from mallet LDA object?

Tags: r, text-mining, lda, mallet

I am trying to use a `mallet` topic model with the `LDAvis` package. [To do so you must extract a number of parameters](http://cpsievert.github.io/LDAvis/newsgroup/newsgroup.html) from the `topic.model` object: `phi`, `theta`, `vocab`, `doc.length`, and `term.frequency`.

The `mallet` [documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mallet/mallet.pdf) makes no mention of these parameters. How can I extract them from a `topic.model` object generated from data using `mallet.import()` and `MalletLDA()`?

So far, I've used mallet to fit the topic model:

```
id_numbers <- as.integer(c(1, 2, 3))

comments <- c("words to be used for text mining", "that may or may not be interesting", "but could serve as a good example")

df <- data.frame(id_numbers, comments, stringsAsFactors = F)

# Set up topic model
library(mallet)

stoplist <- c("to", "be", "or")
write.csv(stoplist, file = "example_stoplist.csv")

mallet.instances <- mallet.import(
  as.character(df$id_numbers),
  as.character(df$comments),
  "example_stoplist.csv",
  FALSE,
  token.regexp="[\\p{L}']+")

topic.model <- MalletLDA(num.topics=10)
topic.model$loadDocuments(mallet.instances)
vocabulary <- topic.model$getVocabulary()
word.freqs <- mallet.word.freqs(topic.model)
topic.model$setAlphaOptimization(40, 80) # tweaking optimization interval and burn-in iterations)
topic.model$train(400)

topic.words.m <- mallet.topic.words(topic.model, smoothed=TRUE,
                                normalized=TRUE)
dim(topic.words.m)

vocabulary <- topic.model$getVocabulary() 
colnames(topic.words.m) <- vocabulary 

doc.topics.m <- mallet.doc.topics(topic.model, smoothed=T,
                              normalized=T)


doc.topics.df <- as.data.frame(doc.topics.m)
doc.topics.df <- cbind(id_numbers, doc.topics.df)

doc.topic.means.df <- aggregate(doc.topics.df[, 2:ncol(doc.topics.df)],
                                list(doc.topics.df[,1]),
                                mean)
```

Out of this I now need to generate the `JSON` for `LDAvis`. I tried the following:

```
# LDAvis
library(LDAvis)
phi <- t(mallet.topic.words(topic.model, smoothed = TRUE, normalized = TRUE))
phi.count <- mallet.topic.words(topic.model, smoothed = TRUE, normalized = FALSE)

topic.words <- mallet.topic.words(topic.model, smoothed=TRUE, normalized=TRUE)
topic.counts <- rowSums(topic.words)

topic.proportions <- topic.counts/sum(topic.counts)

vocab <- topic.model$getVocabulary() 

doc.tokens <- data.frame(id=c(1:nrow(doc.topics.m)), tokens=0)
for(i in vocab){
  # Find word if word in text
  matched <- grepl(i, df$comments)
  doc.tokens[matched,2] =doc.tokens[matched,2] +  1
}

createJSON(phi = phi, 
           theta = doc.topics.m, 
           doc.length = doc.tokens, 
           vocab = vocab, 
           term.frequency = apply(phi.count, 1, sum))
```

However, this gives me the following error message:

```
Error in createJSON(phi = phi, theta = doc.topics.m, doc.length = doc.tokens,  : 
  Number of rows of phi does not match 
      number of columns of theta; both should be equal to the number of topics 
      in the model.
```

So I seem to be generating the phi and theta matrices in the wrong way.

Comment: Please attempt to provide some sort of [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input data so we can see what you are trying to do and can test possible solutions.

Comment: What does `str` on your mallet object produce?

Comment: @emilliman5: `str(topic.model)` gives `Formal class 'jobjRef' [package "rJava"] with 2 slots
  ..@ jobj  :<externalptr> 
  ..@ jclass: chr "cc/mallet/topics/RTopicModel"`

Comment: I don't think you need to transform `mallet.topic.words` to generate `phi`. Look at the dimensions of `phi`. `theta` and `doc.length` to get them squared away.

Comment: If you do not mind using the `lda` package, you have data in the format which is compatible with the LDAvis package.

Answer (score 3):

Try removing the matrix transpose function `t()` from the line where you create `phi`.

RMallet is returning these matrices in the format expected by LDAvis: topics are columns for document topics (`theta`) and rows for topic words (`phi`). Sometimes it makes sense to flip one of them so that either rows or columns always means topics, but not here.